# Unable to send email with attachment exceed 2MB

Tags: php, laravel-4, email-attachments

I am using Laravel 4.2.

My mail sever unable to send email with attachment exceed 2MB.  Is there a config file to set maximum file size?

Many thanks

Comment: 2mb is pretty much the maximum file size of email attachment. i'm guessing you're using gmail as your smtp host?

Comment: i am not using gmail.

Comment: It probably depends on the mail server you are using. You never mention what it is.

Comment: 'driver' => 'mail','host' => 'smtp.company.com','port'=25,

Comment: if you have no control over the mailserver, then no, obviously you cant do anything.

Comment: any other suggestion....

Comment: post_max_size = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 64M

Comment: @Dr.Stitch I send 10-20MB attachments all the time in Gmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini file.

> Search for upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in php.ini file and change it to desired maximum filesize (100m) you need.

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 1000M
```